# How do you determine the results for a single line in a truth table?

Tags: logic

[image: Truth Table]

I apologies if this question is stupid but I can't find anywhere how the results for a single line like that are found. I understand everything else but where did this T F T F come from?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: They just appear to be the truth values of $q$. In fact, that column is an exact copy of the third one and the seventh one.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli but where are these found? How are these determined? I'm completely lost?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Oh so had the q been a p, would that just be T T F F then?

Comment: $q$ can take either and $p$ can take either. So the expression must be evaluated when $p$ is $T$ and $q$ is $T$, when $p$ is $T$ and $q$ is $F$, when $p$ is $F$ and $q$ is $T$ and when $p$ is $F$ and $q$ is $F$.

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the different truth values for q.

If you see the first three columns, under p and q, the pairs are all different (when p is T and q is T, when p is T and q is F, etc.) and you're assessing what (p v q) is for these different values of p and q.

Notice that all the q columns are the same, as well as all the p columns.

Hope that's helpful!